# Unable to connect to connect to Postgres server using DB Manager: unable to convert a QVariant of type 10 to a QMetaType of type 2

Tags: postgis, qgis-3, dbmanager

Using QGIS 3.0.3 and QGIS 3.1 nightly, I can't connect to a postgres Database using the DB Manager and get the following error:

> TypeError: unable to convert a QVariant of type 10 to a QMetaType of type 2

I get the same error when I try to open the "Import into PostGIS" function in the Processing toolbox.

However the browser has no problems connecting to the databases.

Does someone know how to solve this error and be able to use PostGIS with the DB Manager on QGIS 3?

Comment: Please ask only one question per Question.

Comment: Sorry if I broke a rule, but reading my question again, I still only see one question. Let me know how I can change the question if I'm not respecting the site policy

Comment: Your last sentence has two questions.

Comment: It doesn't. The second part is the consequence of the first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved in QGIS 3.2 and QGIS 3.3.